# How to do urlencode, rawurlencode, urldecode, rawurldecode in Java?

Tags: java, web-applications, protocols

How do you do RAW/URL encode/decode in JAVA?

Got something which asked URLencoded or RAWURLencoded need to be sent. After looking here and there, did not find any url/rawurl encoder/decoder available. How do you make it?

Example:

```
String webBrowser = "how=WebRSS&what=Tandory chicken is nice with rice, lets cook for my honey";
String encoded = null;

/**
 * Output: how%3DWebRSS%26what%3DTandory+chicken+is+nice+with+rice%2C+lets+cook+for+my+honey
 */
urlencode(webBrowser); 

/**
 * Output: how%3DWebRSS%26what%3DTandory%20chicken%20is%20nice%20with%20rice%2C%20lets%20cook%20for%20my%20honey
 */
rawurlencode(webBrowser);

postIt(encoded); //!!
```

Comment: I'm confused, what are you looking for?

Comment: RAWURLencoder. Such as %20 instead of +.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)/[`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode) (the application/x-www-form-urlencoded variants), you can use [`URLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)
 and [`URLDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

For the "raw" versions, you can use the [`URI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class, which performs this task automatically.

Comment: Could you add an example of URI usage?

Answer (score 1):

If you want "%20" (for example), then you you want to use [java.net.URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).  Which implements [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).