# how to implement from php rawurlencode to java

Tags: java, php

i have question

i have php code like this :

```
 $auth_header = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) . '"';
```

how to implement rawurlencode from php on java code ? or change to java code

```
"OAuth realm=\""+ URLEncoder.encode("accountId",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\","
                + "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\","
                + "oauth_token=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\","
                + "oauth_signature_method=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("HMAC-SHA256",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\","
                + "oauth_timestamp=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(oauthTimestamp),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())+ "\","
                + "oauth_nonce=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthNonce,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()).replace("*", "%2a").replace("+", "%20") + "\","
                + "oauth_version=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("1.0",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\","
                + "oauth_signature=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(signature,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())+"\"";
```

because if i see on php and on java there is different value

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464077/7525132), Java's `URLEncoder` is equivalent to PHP's `urlencode()`. For `rawurlencode()`, however, it suggests using `URI`, which seems to be not applicable here, as the encoded strings are not URIs.

Comment: ya i want to know what is equivalent of urlrawencode() php on java ?